# Format input type date to value from database

Tags: php, html

so I am using the input type="date" in my form and it shows mm/dd/yyyy and my current code in my form is `<input type="date" value="<?= $row['bdate']; ?>">` and it still shows mm/dd/yyyy instead of a date like 10/01/1992. Is there a way to accomplish a thing like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date should take the format YYYY-MM-DD. Single digit days and months should be padded with a 0. January is 01.

A string representing a date.

Value: A valid full-date as defined in [RFC 3339], with the additional qualification that the year component is four or more digits representing a number greater than 0.

```
<input type="date" value="2013-01-08">
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfkU5/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the format while setting the value. Try with -

```
<input type="date" value="<?= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['bdate'])); ?>">
```

Or  -

```
<input type="date" value="<?= date('d/m/Y', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $row['bdate']))); ?>">
```

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Comment: Thanks for this. Tried and still the same

Comment: Still getting mm-dd-yyyy :(